# Creating an outline edge loop with even distances

Tags: modeling, mesh, extrude

I'm trying to create an edge loop with even spaces and have it align with the edge that i have highlighted. I essentially just want an edge loop that represents the white outline around the jacket, and with an even thickness to it.

I've opted to try to extrude to get that new edge loop, but can't get my extruded edges to extrude along the same angle of my mesh's edges. Upon some research i've read that extruding along vertex normals may solve this issue, but i'm on 2.90.1 and i can't see that option anywhere.

[image]

Comment: it won't work except if your object has thickness, or you can try the opposite with an inset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a triangle in your edge loop, similar to the one at the point I've highlighted here.

[image: highlighted triangle]

I would add some geometry to remove the triangle before I continued:

[image: added geometry]

Then create two edge loops, one horizontal and one vertical.  They'll have even distance:

[image: added edge loops]

Now you can alter the edge flow to make the whole thing one face loop, but if you're planning on animating I'd argue for leaving the all quad geometry.

EDIT:  If you want to convert the bottom of the geometry so that a face loop will flow around the corner, change the geometry of the bottom corner

[image: bottom corner]

by connecting the corner vertex to the intersection vertex and deleting the two now redundant edges:

[image: modified bottom corner]

Now when you try to select the face loop it will select both the horizontal and vertical portions.